# How to manage templates as per users in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to implement Docusign in one of my projects. I have multiple dynamic users and I want to create multiple separate templates for separate users. **1)** Also, the users can manage/edit only their template inside the site, not in the DocuSign portal. **2)** Is there anything multiple users or subaccount in DocuSign so that I can manage it by creating a subaccount or user in DocuSign and assign one of the dynamic users to my site.

What does this API do? Can I manage templates as per users created following these APIs?

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "newUsers": [
    {
      "userName": "Claire Horace",
      "email": "claire@example.com"
    },
    {
      "userName": "Tal Mason",
      "email": "talmason@example.com",
      "company": "TeleSel",
      "userSettings": {
        "locale": "fr",
        "canSendEnvelope": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion would help me a lot who already have worked on DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

This API add new users to your account.
In the developer environment you can do that at will, but once your app is eventually running in production - that is limited to the number of seats purchased from DocuSign.
Adding users dynamically therefore is not a good idea. Not sure the use-case exactly, but if you need dynamic users I suggest they exist only in your app and your db and not directly in DocuSign. You can use meta-data on the templates to indicate things that you need to know about them, including which user(s) they are for.

As for sub-accounts, they are simply called accounts and they can be part of an organization that have multiple accounts, but they cannot share template, only users and other settings.